# StringBuffer variable value not coming in full in eclipse debug

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, stringbuffer

I am debugging java code in eclise.
Came through the StringBuffer holding very big query.
If I see this in variables panel, I can not see the full value , I want to copy this query and run it in db server.

StringBuffer value comes like:
`Very long query goes till it can and then dot dot dot like...`

Can I increase size of StringBuffer in variables or something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about printing it to console and seeing there ? :)

Comment: @Foolish did you tried copying the StringBuffer into clipboard from the variables panel ?

Comment: Console window buffer size *can* be increased.

Comment: yes. It comes with same value as shown with `...`